Different FFT results
I am trying to take IQ data from 2 SDRs and process that data in MATLAB. The ultimate goal is to use the Goertzel algorithm to grab the magnitude/phase information at a specific frequency under test.
The issue I am running into is that I am unable to reconcile the differences in the FFT plots I am getting in GNU Radio Companion and MATLAB. There are a couple spurs in the bandwidth, which when translated from GRC to MATLAB have an erroneous magnitude. (You can see these spurs on the left of the FFT at about 3.444GHz and 3.445GHz). Additionally, my frequency under test (3.45GHz) is a much lower magnitude than says GRC.
GNU Radio

MATLAB

As an aside, there does exist a toolbox for live interfacing between MATLAB and this SDR, however it does not support the use of multiple devices (which I am using).
Any guidance would be appreciated! Thanks
Fs = 10e6;
N = 262144;
A=resize(A,N);   %A is a vector of IQ data
B=resize(B,N);   %B is a vector of IQ data

center_freq = 3.448e9;
lower_bound = center_freq - (Fs/2);
upper_bound = center_freq + (Fs/2);

freq=lower_bound : Fs/N : upper_bound;
freq=resize(freq, N)';

D=blackmanharris(N);
   correction = 2.80;   %BH correction factor according to SIEMENS

A_mag = abs(fft(A.*D)/length(A))*correction;
A_mag_dB = 20*log10(A_mag);

B_mag = abs(fft(B.*D)/length(B))*correction;
B_mag_dB = 20*log10(B_mag);

A_phase = angle(A)*(180/pi);
B_phase = angle(B)*(180/pi);

figure(1)
   subplot(2, 1, 1)
   plot(freq, A_mag_dB);
   hold on
   grid
   title("Magnitude 1")
   xlabel("Frequency [Hz]")
   ylabel("Magnitude [dBV]")

   subplot(2, 1, 2)
   plot(freq, B_mag_dB);
   grid
   title("Magnitude 2")
   xlabel("Frequency [Hz]")
   ylabel("Magnitude [dBV]")
   hold off


Your code is not complete, how do you plot the data in MATLAB? We can’t see how you assigned a frequency to each on the N element in A_mag_dB. But the N elements in freq are definitely not them, so if you do plot(freq, A_mag_dB)` you will see the wrong stuff.

@CrisLuengo Apologies, I have added the plots to the code. I am unsure why it would not work to plot against the frequencies? It seems to give me the same output by plotting against a vector (0 : N-1)

It looks the same, but the x-axis won’t be the same. You’re looking at peaks, their location along the x-axis is wrong. If in GNU Radio you plotted the spectrum and then zoomed in to your desired region, you’d have to do the same in MATLAB. Just setting the x-axis values to the range you’re interested in doesn’t mean you get to see those frequencies. When you call fft, the function doesn’t know which frequencies you want to see, it computes the values for a standard set of normalized frequencies 0…N-1.

@CrisLuengo I understand the window of the FFT is limited in bandwidth by my sample rate, and how many bins I have defined here, the FFT has an output from (0:N-1)*Fs/N. However, the output of the SDR has a DDC which converts the RF signal to baseband, so the x-axis isn't entirely relevant, outside of providing a ruler for my predefined bandwidth. The peaks definitely line up with the frequencies from GRC, and I have confirmed that with phase experimentation. What doesn't make sense to me is not the window of the FFT, but why I would be getting different magnitudes on the same data?

If that is the case, it is likely that center_freq is the leftmost bin, not the one in the middle of the FFT. Try plotting plot(freq, fftshift(A_mag_dB)), it looks like that will match your GNU Radio output fairly well.

But it seems that the MATLAB output has larger swings in values (the peaks are a bit higher and the noisy band in wider). This might be an issue with the plotting in GNU Radio. You have way too many points for a useful line plot. Can GNU Radio make the plot as dots? Or maybe you can export the results from GNU Radio, import them in MATLAB, and plot them there? That would make any deviation of the plot from the data be consistent for the two plots.

@CrisLuengo It is definitely different magnitudes because of Parseval's thm. The magnitudes would be the same given the same number of bins. (32768 in GRC versus 262144 in MATLAB). I did replot using fftshift() and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much, Cris. Is there a way I can close the question as answered? Sorry, brand new to DSP stack exchange.

1.
In MATLAB to filter signals using specific windows one does not just dot product signal samples with window samples as done in the code of this question.
Such direct approach requires at least correlating chosen time window with signal, not just dot product.
MATLAB has specific commands to time window filter and display signals spectrum.
For instance, following how to use a basic rectangular window, from MATLAB help :
t = linspace(-pi,pi,100);
rng default  %initialize random number generator
x = sin(t) + 0.25*rand(size(t));
windowSize = 5; 
b = (1/windowSize)*ones(1,windowSize);
a = 1;
y = filter(b,a,x);

plot(t,x)
hold on
plot(t,y)
legend('Input Data','Filtered Data')

The filtering is done by function filter and a b coefficients are needed, coefficients generated from the choice of window.
2.
y=filtfilt(b,a,x)

does the same as filter but with zero-phase
Example also from MATLAB help :
wform = ecg(500);

plot(wform)
axis([0 500 -1.25 1.25])
text(155,-0.4,'Q')
text(180,1.1,'R')
text(205,-1,'S')

rng default

x = wform' + 0.25*randn(500,1);
d = designfilt('lowpassfir', ...
    'PassbandFrequency',0.15,'StopbandFrequency',0.2, ...
    'PassbandRipple',1,'StopbandAttenuation',60, ...
    'DesignMethod','equiripple');
y = filtfilt(d,x);
y1 = filter(d,x);

subplot(2,1,1)
plot([y y1])
title('Filtered Waveforms')
legend('Zero-phase Filtering','Conventional Filtering')

subplot(2,1,2)
plot(wform)
title('Original Waveform')

d1 = designfilt('lowpassiir','FilterOrder',12, ...
    'HalfPowerFrequency',0.15,'DesignMethod','butter');
y = filtfilt(d1,x);

subplot(1,1,1)
plot(x)
hold on
plot(y,'LineWidth',3)
legend('Noisy ECG','Zero-Phase Filtering')

function x = ecg(L)
% ...

a0 = [0,1,40,1,0,-34,118,-99,0,2,21,2,0,0,0]; % Template
d0 = [0,27,59,91,131,141,163,185,195,275,307,339,357,390,440];
a = a0 / max(a0);
d = round(d0 * L / d0(15)); % Scale them to fit in length L
d(15)=L;

for i=1:14,
       m = d(i) : d(i+1) - 1;
       slope = (a(i+1) - a(i)) / (d(i+1) - d(i));
       x(m+1) = a(i) + slope * (m - d(i));
end

3. Try pwelch
example
n = 0:511;
x = cos(pi/3*n)+randn(size(n));
segmentLength = 132;

[pxx,w] = pwelch(x,segmentLength);

plot(w/pi,10*log10(pxx))
xlabel('\omega / \pi')

4. Try pspectrum

[P,f]=pspectrum(x,fs)

x time signal
fs sampling rate in [Hz]

Example
Fs = 1000;
t = (0:1/Fs:0.296)';
x = cos(2*pi*t*200)+0.1*randn(size(t));
xTable = timetable(seconds(t),x);
[pxx,f] = pspectrum(xTable);

plot(f,pow2db(pxx))
grid on
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ylabel('Power Spectrum (dB)')
title('Default Frequency Resolution')

Change frequency resolution like this

pspectrum(xTable,'FrequencyResolution',25)

4.
Use dsp.SpectrumAnalyzer
To open dsp.SpectrumAnalyzer
scope = dsp.SpectrumAnalyzer();
show(scope); 

Either directly on the scope playing with the instrument buttons
or with the SIMULINK block Spectrum Analyzer
Link to SIMULINK SA block details
So
generateScript(scope);

% Creation Code for 'dsp.SpectrumAnalyzer'.
% Generated by Spectrum Analyzer on 10-Mar-2019 16:25:49 -0500.

specScope = dsp.SpectrumAnalyzer('ViewType','Spectrum and spectrogram', ...
    'AxesLayout','Horizontal');
% Cursor Measurements Configuration
specScope.CursorMeasurements.Enable = true;

mask = SpectralMaskSpecification();
mask.EnabledMasks = 'Upper';
mask.UpperMask = 10;
scope = dsp.SpectrumAnalyzer();
scope.SpectralMask = mask;
scope.SpectralMask

 [~,mdl] = fileparts(tempname);
  open_system(new_system(mdl,'FromTemplate','dsp_basic_filter'));
  saBlock = find_system(mdl,'BlockType','SpectrumAnalyzer');

  scopeConfig = get_param(saBlock{1},'ScopeConfiguration');
  upperMask = [0 50; 1200 50; 1200 -10; 24000 -10];
  scopeConfig.SpectralMask.UpperMask = upperMask;
  scopeConfig.SpectralMask.LowerMask = -100;
  scopeConfig.SpectralMask.EnabledMasks = 'Upper and lower';

  sim(mdl,'StopTime','20');

these lines generate the following SIMULINK example

Modify this SIMULINK circuit to compare MATLAB generated sample with the external signal.
5.
One can directly configure the following windows directly with this instrument:

Window Option       Signal Processing Toolbox Function
"Rectangular"         rectwin
"Chebyshev"           chebwin
"Flat Top"            flattopwin
"Hamming"             hamming
"Hann"                hann
"Kaiser"              kaiser
"BLACKMAN-HARRIS" blackmanharris

6.-
Regarding the following line in this question
correction = 2.80;   %BH correction factor according to SIEMENS

Time windowing "per se", meaning, just because time windowing a signal, with one of the basic time windows listed above, by no means an amplification of 2.8 (dB(W)? linear? dBmV?) should be applied.
... according SIEMENS     really?
